# Basic or base?What's the correct one?

Tags: grammar

"I speak basic french"
or
"I speak base french"?
"My french knowledge is at a basic level"
or
"My french knowledge is at a base level"?

I know that basic is just an adjective, while base can be an adjective, a verb and a noun.
Nevertheless, when you want to express your knowledge of a language or your ability level in any discipline what's the most correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic is the right adjective.

Base is (I believe) only a verb and noun (at least in common use):

> base
>   **noun**
>   1. the lowest part or edge of something, especially the part on which it rests or is supported. "she sat down at the base of a tree"
>
> **verb**
>   1. have as the foundation for (something); use as a point from which (something) can develop. "the film is based on a novel by Pat Conroy"

Comment: _Base_ is also an adjective meaning ‘ignoble, morally reprehensible’ or used of coins that are made of non-precious metals (though this latter sense is not really in what you’d call common use).

Comment: @Janus, Yeah, I did more research and edited that in when I realised.

Comment: @Tim +1 for being first with a researched answer

Answer (score 1):

Use "basic", not "base": "I speak basic french" and "My french knowledge is at a basic level".

The online oxford dictionary defines "[basic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/basic)" as an adjective meaning: Forming an essential foundation or starting point; fundamental.

"Base" is not an adjective that can be applied to a language, like French.

Comment: @Tim I was in too much of a rush to answer :) I also did some research and edited.